# ios/objective-c: Error saving in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to save an object created from some JSON in core data and it is not saving.  I suspect the problem is that I am creating the managed object context too many times or trying to save to the wrong managed object context.  I have to keep declaring it as I was getting managedobjectcontext = nil errors.  Wondering if anyone could help me spot bug which has eluded me.

```
-(void) importItems:(NSArray *)ItemsToImport
{
    int i;
    int max = [itemsToImport count];
    IDItemServer *importItem;//this is import object
    Items *Item; //this is core data entity

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    for (i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"value of i is%d:",i);
        importItem = ItemsToImport[i];

            NSString *name = importItem.name;
            NSString *sub = importItem.sub;
     //save our new and updated changes to the Core Data store
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [IDModel sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;

            NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        //was self.managedObjectContext
        // Initialize Record
        NSManagedObject *record = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

            // Populate Record
         [record setValue:name forKey:@“name”];
         [record setValue:sub forKey:@“s”ub];

        }
            // Save Record
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSLog(@"BEFORE SAVE”);//Logs to console
        if ([context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"AFTER SAVE”);//does not log to console


        } else {
        if (error) {

        NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);//does not log to console
        }

        // Show Alert View
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Your Item could not be saved." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
//THIS ALERT FIRES
        }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have so many different MOCs?  Are they really different?  And how are they created?  Unless they are all NSMainQueueConcurrencyType, you are violating all kinds of core data rules.  Also, please explain what you expect this code to do, and what it is doing that is not right.  Just saying it is not saving is not good enough.  If you are not getting log messages, then what happens when you step through the debugger?  Also, there is something wrong with your code example.  I tried to reformat it to make it easier to read, and you have unbalanced braces, indicating other issues.

Comment: This method is actually called from another method called from another method in viewdidload. Since there is already a lazy loaded MOC in VC, initially I thought that would suffice.  But I got MOC is nil errors.  To get rid of these, following an answer on SO, I kept adding MOCs but probably there are too many.  I will try cutting them out.  (Extra brace is a result of cutting out a lot of extraneous commented code and notes.)

Comment: I doubt you will get much help until you edit your question.  I know I won't even try to read it again until I see that it has been significantly updated.

Comment: The code has been simplified as much as possible to still show the issue. No need for you to read it again if you find it it taxing.

Answer (score 0):

There was indeed an unnecessary context here.  The one on line 8 should be deleted.  Also check that whenever you invoke or use a MOC you are using a consistent name i.e. "* context" vs. "* managedobjectcontext"